# Intercept data at the kernel block I/O layer

Tags: linux, file-io, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I would like to intercept data that is transferred between the block I/O layer in the linux kernel and a disk. My goal is to gather some stats on data that is transferred between the host (through OS) and disk. For example, I would like to know how many times a specific character appears in each transferred block. I need to gather this info at block level since all operations between disk and host is done at block granularity.

Note: I am not sure that if `bio` struct and `bio_vec` should be used or not.

Comment: I suggest to look at `blktrace`. It can report a lot of info on request to particular disk, e.g. time, size, status and so on. But I'm not sure whether it can trace data transferred in your requests. Anyway I would suggest looking in blktrace sources to see how it gets info on requests.

Comment: yeah, I have used blktrace. Unfortunately, it does not give you pointers to the data buffer. But as you suggested I will take a look at its source to get a sense of how it intercepts block I/O events. Thanks!

Comment: I just can't imagine how you can intercept data in block layer. Block drivers don't have any kind of API like netfilter hooks. So you can either modify particular block driver or block scheduler.

Comment: seems you can use device mapper to trace the content, but it might not so efficient.

Comment: @arsane can you give me some pointers on where to edit or how to start?

Comment: @arsane, good point about device mapper. aminfar, you can wrap your block device with simple device mapper target. In dm you will get every BIO sent along with data. You can start with trivial dm-zero and dm-linear, and add necessary tracing functionality (chars logging, etc.). But, you should be aware that device mapper subsystem may modify original BIOs, e.g. merge it and reorder, so if you care about order of BIOs then dm is not your solution.

Comment: @avd the order of BIOs matter to me. So DM is not an option :(.

Comment: @avd Would you please elaborate why DM changes order of BIOs ? Is there anyway to eliminate that ?

Comment: @ARH, well, if you set up max_io_len in your target with `dm_set_target_max_io_len` then request will be split by the io_len boundary. This is required in some targets like dm-stripe or dm-raid1. But anyway, I'm really not sure whether dm or block scheduler won't split, merge or reorder your request if you write a simplest possible dm target like dm-zero that will just dump bio data. It has to be checked :-\

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can hook to the block layer with kprobes/systemtap. I guess it is the least invasive method to do that. Basically, systemtap alone should suffice, but you can anyway write your own kernel module and install kporbes by hand.